# D365 UCI menu items linking to specific system views

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-uci

In using the new UCI interface with Dynamics 365, the menu editor allows me to create a menu item on the left that goes to a particular entity (in this case, Contacts).

WIthin Contacts, I have two saved views:  "Supplier Contacts" and "Client Contacts".

I'm wanting to create two separate menu items that takes me straight to these particular system views.  Is there a way to do this with the UCI App editor or do I need to put in a relative URL to the GUID representing the system view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would recommend is create two dashboards, add a list in each, set the “Supplier Contacts” as the view in first dashboard list component and “Client Contacts” in the other one. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customize/create-edit-dashboards)

Turn off the view selector in list component properties. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customize/set-properties-chart-list-included-dashboard)

You can add multiple Dashboard links in UCI sitemap (left navigation).

Comment: Thanks Arun - I think this strategy is the best way to do it.  Should note that I created Dashboards in the root of the Solution (not within the entity as I did not want an interactive dashboard).  I made the top tab of the dashboard hidden so that the only element is the full-width list in the second row.  Unfortunately it does not take up the full height, however, using the app designer I can now link directly to it in the menu.  Thanks again!